# For iAd, what means to be an impression?

Tags: iphone, iad, impressions

Say I have a view that will show an iAd banner once the view is loaded/appear, does it mean that the # of times that the view appears == the # of impressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the iAd code calls the server (# of requests) and when it gets an answer your code displays the ad (# of impressions).